# Mobile: Embedding Images for Speed

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air, flex4.5

Would embedding images in mobile Air applications speed up the process of drawing the UI that uses images?

How does one properly embed the images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of embedding an images is that it is included in the SWF file, and can be accessed faster than it can if the application has to load it from a remote location at run time. but it also have disadvantage that is your SWF file is larger than if you load the asset at run time.

The embed process is very simple, just follow to follow steps:

1. copy your image files where the "src" folder is of your application. the Flex 4 will get these files from there. Of course you may define sub folders to do not mess up.
2. In your class define like the example bellow
   [Embed (source="728x90a.jpg" )] 
   public static const imgData1:Class;

   ```
   The 728x90a.jpg is the file name of the image (I didn't use sub folders here)
   The imgData1 is the object where contains the data of the embedded image!
   ```
3. Somewhere in your code, load the data into a visual component, like the example bellow
   img1.source=imgData1;
               The img1 is an Image component.

   ```
   package
   {
      public class TestProjectAssets
      {
           [Embed(source="fonts/MySuperDuperFont.otf",
               fontFamily="SuperDuperFont",
               mimeType="application/x-font",
               embedAsCFF="true")]
           private const SuperDuperFont:Class;

           [Embed(source="assets/mainMenu.png")]
            public static const mainMenuImg:Class;
      }
   }
   ```

If you need to handle a large number of resources you can follow these 3 steps:

```
Place them in an uncompressed zip archive

Embed the zip file as binary data:

[Embed(source = 'resources.zip', mimeType = 'application/octet-stream')]

Access the resources using [FZip][1]
```

If you choose a different method that involves loading external files be aware that some flash game websites require the games they host to be contained within a single swf file.